# Json to Chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

We got this file from the Internet and somehow we can able to get the output as `JSON` in the `console` but the `chartdisplay.js` is not taking the `JSON` file.

Can you help me.
Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/chartjs/chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chartdisplay.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container"> <!-- we have defined width and height for this class -->
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','beehive_exp');

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
    }

$query = sprintf("SELECT userid, facebook, twitter, googleplus FROM followers");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

**chartdisplay.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://192.100.1.100/content.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var userid = [];
            var facebook_follower = [];
            var twitter_follower = [];
            var googleplus_follower = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                userid.push("UserID " + data[i].userid);
                facebook_follower.push(data[i].facebook);
                twitter_follower.push(data[i].twitter);
                googleplus_follower.push(data[i].googleplus);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: userid,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "facebook",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        data: facebook_follower
                    },
                    {
                        label: "twitter",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        data: twitter_follower
                    },
                    {
                        label: "googleplus",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        data: googleplus_follower
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata
                });
            },
        error : function(data) {
            }
        });
    });
```

This is what we get

[image]

**JSON output**

[image]

**PHP Output**

[image]

Comment: can u post the error you are getting ?

Comment: @UmairFarooq I have updated the post with the issue. Please see it. The image is added at the bottom.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` outputs? Please check your browser's Inspector, Console and Network tab.

Comment: It will be easy if you post sample of your JSON or the output log of console

Comment: I an having difficulty in identifying the problem. Please post the console log of all 4 arrays after their population in for loop.

Comment: no the output of all four arrays after for loop.

Comment: @UmairFarooq there is nothing in the output chart. If we run the html file we get only blank chart (which i have displayed on top)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122263/discussion-between-beekeeper-and-umair-farooq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We continued in the chat and the problem I found was that the data he was getting from the php file was in JSON string.

So, in first line of success function, I wrote

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

and the same code worked after and showed the graph as expected.

Comment: Also the loop was corrected `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                userid.push("UserID " + data[i].userid);
                facebook_follower.push(data[i].facebook);
                twitter_follower.push(data[i].twitter);
                googleplus_follower.push(data[i].googleplus);
                }`

Comment: Please use the old loop. I am sure that wasn't the issue.